# Use typescript to dynamically set class property in constructor

Tags: typescript, class, generics, dynamic

I am trying create a typescript class `MyClass` with instance properties set dynamically in the constructor:

```
const myInstance = new MyClass(({
  someField: 'foo'
}))

myInstance.someField // typescript should show this as type string
```

How can I use typescript to create `MyClass` to show `someField` as a string property of `myInstance`?

Can I use generics? Is it at all possible?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wenr1N), maybe?  TypeScript doesn't let you do this with a `class` declaration, since for `class` and `interface`s, the keys must be statically known.  Instead you need to write use a type assertion or other declaration to tell the compiler that `MyClass` acts as a constructor producing some object type with dynamic keys.  If that works for you I could maybe write up an answer (although I'm 85% sure I've written up that answer before so I should find it maybe). If it doesn't work please [edit] the code in the question to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: This works! I edited [your example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCAbAhgZ1QFXBAPBqEAHsBAHYAmqUAShAMYD2ATuTqsEwJakDmANFACupANakGAd1IA+aVAC8UDAFgAUGsal2sBCnQKodPVQCCpXWlQA5ZAFtoAbzVQXhhlo6C6wZgApkTDwAXEKi4lIAlFBOqq5xUADyAEYAVvTAAHSWnDykvsAAFpyoAgE8Ec6uAL5qVVBoUKQQElB4BMRklDT0zKzsXLwCwmKSMtL+gSEYUfJycEiWWJB40mpqAPSbW9s7m2uqmtq2IACSHsikdNCKTS3zxr6+MXGoDPYAYpwQiOQhAOQAMwYDD+tQiFXUqmOZ3YFyuGVeHy+PyAA) for clarity.

Comment: Although i have some difficulty understanding this line: "as new <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(arg: T) => MyClassType<T>"

Comment: what does the "new" operator mean as a type?

Comment: I’m not sure that the change from  `object` to `Record<string, unknown>` is an improvement in clarity. I imagine you made that change to appease some (misguided in my opinion) linter rule but that’s not really making anything more clear (especially if you try to use an interface type for `T` and find out that it matches `object` but not `Record<string, unknown>`). Unless your question is about such things, I plan to leave `object` in the answer I post (when I get a chance to write it up). See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640

Comment: I’m happy to answer these questions in my posted answer when I’m off mobile. See “construct signature” in the TS Handbook docs … https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually you want to say something like `class MyClass<T extends object> extends T` or `class MyClass<T extends object> implements T`, but TypeScript will not allow a `class` instance or an `interface` to have dynamic keys.  All keys of a `class` or `interface` declaration must be statically known.  So if you want this behavior you will need to do something other than a `class` declaration.

Instead, you can describe the type of your desired `MyClass<T>` instances as well as the type of the `MyClass` class constructor, and then use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that your actual constructor object is of that type.

Let's imagine that your intended `MyClass<T>` class instances have all the properties of `T`, plus a method named `someMethodIGuess()`.  Then your `MyClass<T>` type can be defined like this:

```
type MyClass<T extends object> = T & {
    someMethodIGuess(): void;
}
```

You want your `MyClass` class constructor to have a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that takes an argument of type `T` for some [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` object type, and produces an instance of `MyClass<T>`.  That can be defined like this:

```
type MyClassConstructor = {
    new <T extends object>(arg: T): MyClass<T>
}
```

To implement this class we can use [`Object.assign()`] to copy the constructor argument properties into the instance, plus any methods or other things we need.

```
const MyClass = class MyClass {
    constructor(arg: any) {
        Object.assign(this, arg);
    }
    someMethodIGuess() {

    }
}
```

But of course if we leave it like this, the compiler will not see `MyClass` as a `MyClassConstructor` (after all, it can't have dynamic keys, and I didn't even try to tell it about `T` here).  We need a type assertion to tell it so, like this:

```
const MyClass = class MyClass {
    constructor(arg: any) {
        Object.assign(this, arg);
    }
    someMethodIGuess() {

    }
} as MyClassConstructor;
```

That compiles with no error.  Again, note that the compiler is unable to understand that the `MyClass` implementation conforms to the `MyClassConstructor` type.  By using a type assertion, I've shifted the burden of ensuring that it is implemented correctly away from the compiler (which can't do it) to me (or you if you use this code).  So we should be very careful to check what we've done and that we didn't write the wrong thing (e.g., `Object.assign(arg, this);` instead of `Object.assign(this, arg);` would be a problem).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const myInstance = new MyClass(({
    someField: 'foo'
}))

console.log(myInstance.someField.toUpperCase()); // FOO
myInstance.someMethodIGuess(); // okay
```

Looks good!  The compiler expects `myInstance` to have a `someField` property of type `string`, as well as that `someMethodIGuess()` method.

---

So that's it.  Note that there are caveats around using `MyClass` in the same way you'd use another class constructor.  For example, the compiler will never be happy with a `class` declaration that has dynamic keys, so if you try to make a generic subclass of `MyClass` with a `class` declaration, you'll get an error:

```
class SubClass<T extends object> extends MyClass<T> { // error    
    anotherMethod() { }
}
```

If you need that sort of thing you'll find yourself having to use the same trick as before with the subclass:

```
type SubClass<T extends object> = MyClass<T> & { anotherMethod(): void };
type SubClassConstructor = { new <T extends object>(arg: T): SubClass<T> };
const SubClass = class SubClass extends MyClass<any> {
    anotherMethod() { }
} as SubClassConstructor;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class MyClass{
    constructor(props: any) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    baz(): string {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    static create<T>(props = {} as T) {
        return new MyClass(props || {}) as MyClass & T
    }
}

const o = MyClass.create({
    foo: 1,
    bar: "Hello World"
});

console.log(o.foo);
console.log(o.bar);
console.log(o.baz());
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUDeBYAUNH1gHsA7CAFwCcBXYE-MgCgAcz8GIAuaMQ+ASmg2y4hAeQBGAKwCm1AHSQIASwDmhOiQAWCiABpoTFhB4BuLEIC+WU7lFgAXnR4dSZBYSX8rQnGUkkKZQmgAIgAJSRAQfGgAdVoQABMgk0EcC0xPaFIwEgVgPB9syQAeABUAPkZmVmgAXn4zThgSvgEvXB8-AOhCSQB3OCQUCEqDaAAfMfq+SAHkeWgAMmgSjLS0rAJiEmgouoQ5qBlgApJJOlbcADN8fA4ARm0MmzIOUPDImLjErDNjS0xNhB8CBJDJIko6PgZNd8H8AUQgSCwfgIVDnnDAcDQeDITIbPYeHCsEA)

Comment: Thank you, but i would like to call the class with the "new" operator. So this does not work for me. But again thank you!